# Зачем для символов < и > использовать символы-мнемоники, когда они и без этого нормально отображаются на сайте

Tags: html, вёрстка, символы

В моей книге написано, что для отображения на странице специальных символов, таких как <, > и других используются специальные символы-мнемоники. Вопрос: зачем для отображения угловых скобок использовать символы-мнемоники, когда они отображаются если просто их написать?

Comment: `HTML Мнемоники
Существует довольно большое количество символов, которые невозможно отобразить в HTML документе по причине их отсутствия на клавиатуре (ряд математических символов, спецсимволы и т.д.). Есть также символы, которые мы не можем использовать потому, что это приведет к путанице. К примеру, мы не можем использовать знак больше (>), так как в синтаксе разметки этот символ означает тег, а значит браузер его не покажет.`  https://ru.w3docs.com/uchebnik-html/html-simvoly.html - Источник

Comment: Затем, что это спецсимволы в html-синтаксисе и их беспорядочным использованием вы запутываете браузер и нарушаете спецификацию

Answer (score 2):

*Если готовить простым языком.* Суть в том, что вы можете некоторыми символами "сломать" свой код. Например, вам поставили задачу, описать на странице какую-то формулу: `x=i<b>10`. Поскольку оба символа, меньше и больше, при появлении нужного символа внутри образуют тег, браузер это именно так и прочитает. Другими словами символы-мнемоники нужны в тех ситуациях, где без них не обойтись.